# Find the pattern (YYYY-MM-DD) and replace it with the same value concatenating with apostrophes

Tags: bash, shell, sed, nsregularexpression

I have this kind of data:

```
1,1990-01-01,2,A,2015-02-09 
1,NULL,2,A,2015-02-09
1,1990-01-01,2,A,NULL
```

And looking for solution which will replace each date in the file with the old value but adding apostrophes. Basically expected result from the example will be:

```
1,'1990-01-01',2,A,'2015-02-09' 
1,NULL,2,A,'2015-02-09'
1,'1990-01-01',2,A,NULL
```

I have found the way how to find the pattern which match my date, but still can't get with what I can then replace it.

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/????/' a.txt > b.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the date in a group by surrounding the pattern with parentheses `()`. Then you can use this catched group with `\1` (second group would be `\2` etc.).

```
sed "s/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\)/'\1'/g"
```

Note the `g` at the end, which ensures that all matches are replaced (if there are more than one in one line).

---

If you add `-r` switch to sed, the awkward backslashes before `()` can be omitted:

```
sed -r "s/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9])/'\1'/g"
```

---

This can be further simplified using quantifiers:

```
sed -r "s/([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/'\1'/g"
```

Or even:

```
sed -r "s/([0-9]{4}-([0-9]{2}){2})/'\1'/g"
```

---

As mentioned in the comments: Also, in this particular case, you may use `&` instead of `\1`, which matches the whole looked-up expression, and omit the `()`:

```
sed -r "s/[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}/'&'/g"
```

Comment: You could **1.** write `[0-9]{4}` instead of `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`. **2.** Use `&` instead of `\1` such that you don't have to use `(...)` at all.

Comment: you can compress more `[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{2}){2}`

Comment: @karakfa Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!!! I was trying smth more or less like this, but don't really have good understanding of regexp in shell ((

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a capture group, as well as replace *all* matching occurrences with the `g` flag.

```
sed 's/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\)/'"'"'\1'"'"'/g' a.txt > b.txt
```

The replacement text is a bit confusing because a single-quoted string in shell cannot contain a single quote, so you have to close the single-quoted string, then use a double-quoted single-quote. Using `$'...'`-style quoting in `bash` simplies it a bit, at the cost of needing to escape the backslashes.

```
sed $'s/\\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\\)/\'\1\'/g' a.txt > b.txt
```

Or, you can simply double-quote the script, since there's nothing currently in it that is subject to expansion:

```
sed "s/\([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\)/'\1'/g" a.txt > b.txt
```

There is also the special `&` replacement text, which expands to whatever the regular expressions matches, so you can avoid an explicit capture group:

```
sed "s/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/'&'/g" a.txt > b.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]{2,4}-?){3}/'\''&'\''/g' file
```

Depending on your file content, the dates may also be described as `1` or `2` followed by a combination of nine dashes or digits:

```
sed -E 's/[12][-0-9]{9}/'\''&'\''/g" file
```

Comment: That second sed is only good for the next 978 years before it starts breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one in awk:

```
$ awk -v q="'" '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                         # set selimiters
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)                       # loop all fields
        if($i~/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/)  # if field has a date looking string
            $i=q $i q                        # quote it
}1' file
```

Output:

```
1,'1990-01-01',2,A,'2015-02-09'
1,NULL,2,A,'2015-02-09'
1,'1990-01-01',2,A,NULL
```

Comment: As usual nice solution from your sir, I too used match but in a little different manner, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.(REGEX mentioned inside `match` could be written as `[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}` too but since my `awk` is of old version so couldn't test it, you could try it once)

```
awk -v s1="'" '
{
   while(match($0,/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/)){
      val=val substr($0,1,RSTART-1) s1 substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) s1
      $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
   print val
   val=""
}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1,'1990-01-01',2,A,'2015-02-09'
1,NULL,2,A,'2015-02-09'
1,'1990-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

With Perl, it is simple

```
perl -pe ' s/(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)/\x27$1\x27/g '
```

with inputs - \x27 is used for single quotes

```
$ cat liubo.txt
1,1990-01-01,2,A,2015-02-09
1,NULL,2,A,2015-02-09
1,1990-01-01,2,A,NULL

$ perl -pe ' s/(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)/\x27$1\x27/g ' liubo.txt
1,'1990-01-01',2,A,'2015-02-09'
1,NULL,2,A,'2015-02-09'
1,'1990-01-01',2,A,NULL

$
```

If you want to use single quotes, then escape $ and wrap the command in double quotes

```
$ perl -pe " s/(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)/\'\$1\'/g " liubo.txt
1,'1990-01-01',2,A,'2015-02-09'
1,NULL,2,A,'2015-02-09'
1,'1990-01-01',2,A,NULL

$
```